# How to get list of elements by partial class name?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML document in which there is a table with multiple rows defined as:

```
<tr class="row_1"></tr>
<tr class="row_2"></tr>
...
<tr class="row_10"></tr>
```

The total number of rows is unknown.

Is it possible to get all the elements (rows) that start with the class name `row_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is it possible to get all the elements (rows) that start with the class name `row_?`"*

Sure, it is possible. You can *either* use *XPath or LINQ* to express your query when using HAP :

```
HtmlDocument doc;
....
....

var resultXPath = doc.DocumentNode
                     .SelectNodes("//tr[starts-with(@class, 'row_')]");
var resultLINQ = doc.DocumentNode
                    .Descendants("tr")
                    .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class","").StartsWith("row_"));
```