# XPath: Can I collect elements by partial name match?

Tags: xml, xpath

This is similar to [How to get list of elements by partial class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672291/how-to-get-list-of-elements-by-partial-class-name), but I like to use an XML XPath for this:

Consider this variable list of XML elements:

```
<root>
    <Other>...</Other>
    <Item.1>...</Item.1>
    <Item.2>...</Item.2>
    <Item.3>...</Item.3>
    <Something>...</Something>
```

I would like to construct an Xpath that includes all and only the `Item.*` elements.

I can't simply get all the parent's children, though, as there are many other siblings I do not want to have included, and I can't find a rule to exclude them all, either (it's hard to predict what else could all be in there).

There is, however, one behavior that I can rely on: The Item.* elements always start with Item.1 and are all following each other, with no other elems in between.

Is that possible with Xpath?

Comment: You mean something like `//*[starts-with(local-name(), "Item")]`?

Comment: Wow, that looks good. Though, even with the test parser at http://xpatheval.apphb.com/2euz16Yn7 I can't use this expression as it seems to use a rather new syntax. My own parser (lxml for Python) does not seem to support this, either ("Invalid expression").

Comment: Hmm... This is weird. `lxml` actually supports this syntax. Can you share your `Python` code? For provided `xml` sample I got 3 elements with `etree.fromstring("xml goes here").xpath('//*[starts-with(local-name(), "Item")]')`

Comment: Nevermind! I missed the "*" before the "[". Now it works. Please make your comment an answer. A two-liner should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below `XPath` expression to get elements with the names starts with `Item`:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), "Item")]
```